# Floating point calculation has a subtly incorrect result

Tags: c#, xna, floating-point, floating-point-precision

I'm writing a 2D platformer game that has objects with rectangular hitboxes. I'm using XNA, which uses single-precision floats for its Vector2 datatype. Due to the slight inaccuracy of floating point arithmetic, a collision resolution for a sprite puts it very slightly above the top of a given tile as opposed to placing the sprite directly atop the tile.

```
sprite.Position.Y == 240.0694f;
collisionDepth.Y == -0.06945801f;
sprite.Position.Y + collisionDepth.Y == 239.999985f;
correctPosition == 240f;
correctionPosition - (sprite.Position.Y + collisionDepth.Y) == 0.000015f;
```

The incorrect placement causes the sprite to jitter slightly, but strangely only between Y = 240f and Y = 248f.

**My question is:** How can I determine if a given float value is very close to an integral value and how can I round it appropriately?

Comment: I disagree - floating point equality comparison is not my goal. My goal is to determine if a given float is close enough to the nearest integer that it can be set to that integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the `Math.Abs` method to measure the closeness:

```
float dVal = ...;
int iVal = ...;
if (Math.Abs(dVal - iVal) < 0.0001)
{
    // values are very close to each other
}
```

Comment: subtraction is a poor choice when dealing the floating point values that are close. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_of_significance

Comment: @rerun, I know this fact, but I can't understand how it breaks a comparing.

Comment: Well, that was simpler than I expected. Thanks so much, and sorry for the silly question.

Comment: it mean that with some comparison you will get much larger error values especially when the values are very close. it shouldn't matter in most cases.

Comment: @rerun Quite the contrary, subtracting two floating-point values that are close is always exact. This is called the Sterbenz lemma. What is wrong is to assume that the result has any relative accuracy (it may not have any). Comparing the result of the subtraction to a constant is perfectly fine and can be expected to produce results in line with intuition.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the Sterbenz lemma. A quick definition can be found on the second page of these lecture notes: http://perso.ens-lyon.fr/nathalie.revol/teaching/ValCS06-07/lecture-notes2.pdf